# Node.js file extensions inside gzip compression

Tags: node.js, http, download, gzip

I'm want to let the client download `gzip` compressed file on specific url. I got it almost working - downloading `{fileName}.gz` works, but when it is decompressed it contains plain file name, without any extension. My files are images, so I want `.png` or `.jpg` for example. How should I do that? So far I got this:

File is stored on the server, with unique name, generated by `shortid`. On `GET` to the specific `url` I find my product in the database, get the name and set it as filename like so:

```
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.gz");
res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": `image/png`});
```

then the compression:

```
let gzip = zlib.createGzip();
fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  .pipe(gzip)
  .pipe(res);
```

My problem is that setHeader only sets the name of the original file, which is the compressed `.gz` file. How can I set the name of the file to be decompressed to "my-image.png`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like `zlib.Gzip` supports setting the `FNAME` (*"original filename"*) flag, which is required for what you want.

Even so, the standard `gunzip` tool doesn't normally use the original filename anyway; you have to explicitly tell it to use it, so even if it were possible, chances are that your users won't use the proper option to decompress it to its original filename (perhaps the ZIP format is more appropriate, as it's a "real" archive format, whereas Gzip is more or less a single-file-compression format).

Lastly, you have to wonder if compressing PNG or JPG files actually makes sense, because both are already compressed file formats. Perhaps you'll be able to shave a few percent off the file size, but that's it.

**EDIT**: on closer inspection of your question, I now realize that because you already have the original filename, and it's okay to use it as part of the attachment filename, you can just suffix it with `.gz`.

Say that the original name was `my-image.png`:

```
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=my-image.png.gz");
```

When decompressed, that would yield `my-image.png` which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Originally I marked it as accepted, but when I think about it  - I am not sure. What if it isn't image file, but ".txt"? Are you telling me it is impossible to setup default file name after decompression in Node.js?

Comment: @Alex perhaps there's a module that implements Gzip and allows you to set the original filename (unlike the built-in `zlib.Gzip`), but like I said, it entirely depends on the _decompression_ software if that name is actually used (it's not mandatory according to the Gzip standard). macOS Finder doesn't restore to the original filename, `gunzip` (CLI tool) also doesn't (unless explicitly told it should).

Comment: @Alex hmm silly question, but now that I reread your question I wonder if I'm not making things more difficult than they are. Do you have the original name of the file (for instance, `my-image.png`)? If so, can't you set `my-image.png.gz` as the attachment filename? If that file gets decompressed, it should be saved as `my-image.png`, which is what you want I think.

Comment: That's it. Thanks very much :)